# Group by with count()

Tags: mysql, sql

My table content:

```
id  aid
----------
1   1
2   2
3   2
4   4
5   4
```

my sql: select count(*) from table where aid in (1,2,3,4) group by aid

result:

```
count(*)
----------
1
2
2
```

I would like result:

```
count(*)
----------
1
2
0
2
```

I want a count result when aid is 1,2,3,4. What a sql should I use? Thanks for help.
（I‘m use MySQL）

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Time for an obvious statement:
- Data can't "magically appear", it needs to exist somewhere for it to appear in the output.

This is relevant for your desire to have a count of `0` for `aid = 3`.  Because there isn't a record with `aid = 3`, it can't be counted.  It's data that doesn't exist so will never appear in the output.  So we need to force it to exist.

If you have a table that lists all of the `aid` entities, that's easy to do with a `LEFT JOIN`...

```
SELECT
  aid.id,
  COUNT(yourDataTable.aid) AS data_count
FROM
  aid
LEFT JOIN
  yourDataTable
    ON aid.id = yourDataTable.aid
WHERE
  aid.id IN (1,2,3,4)
GROUP BY
  aid.id
```

*(`COUNT(yourDataTable.aid)` does **not** count records where the field is `NULL`.  So the `3` now exists, and the `COUNT()` can return `0`.)*

Comment: aid.id? I don't understand, SELECT FROM 'column'?

Comment: @janekey - In the line before the code I mention `If you have a table that lists all of the aid entities`. So, the code starts with a table with the list of aids and then joins it to your data. If you don't have a table with the list of aids, and you probably should do in a well built schema, then you need to either create one or build it on the fly. Then, by having a table with `1,2,3,4` in it, you can join your data on and create the counts that you want. *[`aid` isn't the field, it's the table with the list of aids.  So, `aid.id` is the `id` field from the `aid` table.]*

Comment: /@Dems - Got your meaning, but it's too trouble to create a new table. I would rather use program to control it. Any way just use a select SQL to solve it?

Comment: @janekey - replace the `aid` table with `(SELECT 1 AS id UNION ALL SELECT 2 AS id UNION ALL SELECT 3 AS id UNION ALL SELECT 4 AS id) AS aid` - This is an inline view. Other options of creating this table "on the fly" have also been suggested in other options.  One way or another you *need* the numbers `1,2,3,4` to exist in a table - be it permanent, temporary, transient, derived, calculated, whatever; without the value `3` somewhere you will never get a count for it.

Answer (score 1):

```
-- your data
DECLARE @Data TABLE (Id int, Aid int)
INSERT INTO @Data VALUES
(1,1),
(2,2),
(3,2),
(4,4),
(5,4);

DECLARE @Relevant TABLE (Id int )
INSERT INTO @Relevant VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4);

-- the query
SELECT Relevant.Id, COUNT(Data.Aid)
FROM @Data Data
RIGHT JOIN @Relevant Relevant ON Data.Aid = Relevant.Id
GROUP BY Data.Aid, Relevant.Id
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps

```
SELECT COLUMN_VALUE, COUNT(BT.AID)
  FROM SO_BUFFER_TABLE_15 BT, TABLE(SYS.DBMS_DEBUG_VC2COLl(1, 2, 3, 4))
 WHERE BT.AID(+) = COLUMN_VALUE
 GROUP BY COLUMN_VALUE
 ORDER BY COLUMN_VALUE
```

Comment: Even RDBMS that support it have now decprecated that syntax. `LEFT JOIN` is now recommended. ANSI-92 has been around for two decades...